# Exercise on bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let X and Y be normal random variables with mean 0, variance $\sigma^2$ and correlation coefficient $\rho \in (-1,1)$, so that the density is given by

$$f(x,y) = \cfrac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2\sqrt{a-\rho^2}}\,\,\exp{\{-\cfrac{1}{2\sigma^2(1-\rho^2)}[x^2 - 2\rho xy+y^2]\}}$$

How to determine the distribution of $Z=\cfrac{X}{Y}$ ?

Comment: Do you know how you in general get the pdf of a random variable $Z=X/Y$ when  you have the joint pdf $f_{XY}(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes, there is the specific formula $f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{|y| f_X(z y)f_Y(y)dy}$

Comment: But how do I find marginals of $f_{X,Y}$? I don't know how to integrate analytically a normal pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=X/Y$ and $W=Y$.

The transformation $z=x/y,\: w=y$ has the inverse transformation

$x=zw, \: y=w$, and

$$
        \bar{J}(z,w) =\begin{vmatrix}
        \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{z}} & \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{w}}  \\
        \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{z}} & \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{w}}  \\
        \end{vmatrix}        
$$

$$
        \bar{J}(z,w)=\begin{vmatrix}
        w & z  \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix} = w        
$$

Now

$$f_{ZW}(z,w) = |w|f_{XY}(zw,w)$$

and the marginal pdf of $Z$ is

$$f_{Z}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|w|f_{XY}(zw,w)dw$$

Comment: Perfect, I got $f_Z(z) = \cfrac{1}{z^2 - 2\rho z +1}$.